# Check if event is coming from a model inside a plugin?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I need all models inside a custom CakePHP plugin to use a database prefix. I'm trying to use an event, as [suggested by @lorenzo](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/4505#issuecomment-76154855).

```
EventManager::instance()->on('Model.initialize', function ($event) {
    $instance = $event->subject();
    $instance->table('prefix_' . $instance->table());
});
```

I'm getting several callbacks from my plugin model as well as DebugKit models, and potentially it could be other models in the application.

Is there a way to tell if a given `$event` is coming from within a plugin?

I have checked `$event->getSubject()` and it contains the corresponding Table class. The only feasible way I could come up with is to check some properties for the plugin name.

- `$event->getSubject()->getRegistryAlias()` is `ExamplePlugin.Posts`
- `$event->getSubject()->getEntityClass()` is `ExamplePlugin\Model\Entity\Post`

I could check if either starts with `ExamplePlugin`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

The fact that basically any PHP namespace can be a plugin means you could do something like that:

```
EventManager::instance()->on('Model.initialize', function (\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) {
    /** @var \Cake\ORM\Table $object */
    $object = $event->getSubject();
    $tableClassName = get_class($object);
    $isApp = str_starts_with($tableClassName, 'App');
});
```

Because your main app's namespace will always begin with `App`

This of course wouldn't distinguish between your private plugins which are located in `plugins` and plugins which are installed via composer and therefore live in the `vendor` directory.

But you could introduce a name prefix to all your private plugins so you can easily distinguish them from any other plugins.